# How to pass to url_for default params?

Tags: python, flask, python-babel

I develops multi language web site.
Pages have URI's like this:

```
/RU/about

/EN/about

/IT/about

/JP/about

/EN/contacts
```

and in jinja2 templates I write:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('about', lang_code=g.current_lang) }}">About</a>
```

I have to write lang_code=g.current_lang in all `url_for` calls.

Is it possible to pass `lang_code=g.current_lang` to `url_for` implicitly? And write only  `{{ url_for('about') }}`

My routers looks like:

```
@app.route('/<lang_code>/about/')
def about():
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `app.url_defaults` to provide default values when building a url.  Use `app.url_value_preprocessor` to extract values from a url automatically.  This is described in [the docs about url processors](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/urlprocessors/).

```
@app.url_defaults
def add_language_code(endpoint, values):
    if 'lang_code' in values:
        # don't do anything if lang_code is set manually
        return

    # only add lang_code if url rule uses it
    if app.url_map.is_endpoint_expecting(endpoint, 'lang_code'):
        # add lang_code from g.lang_code or default to RU
        values['lang_code'] = getattr(g, 'lang_code', 'RU')

@app.url_value_preprocessor
def pull_lang_code(endpoint, values):
    # set lang_code from url or default to RU
    g.lang_code = values.pop('lang_code', 'RU')
```

Now `url_for('about')` will produce `/RU/about`, and `g.lang_code` will be set to RU automatically when visiting the url.

---

[Flask-Babel](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Babel/) provides more powerful support for handling languages.